# Generics and IList related

Tags: c#, generics

i have this code below -- a generic method which takes List as one of the input parameters. within the method, is an IF/ELSEIF statement, which runs into a common LINQ call.
Please help me out, so that the LINQ, call could be common to all the IF/ELSEIF's.

```
private Boolean filterList<T>(List<T> anyOutdoorSports, int numberOfPartcipants)
{
    if (anyOutdoorSports == null){ return false ;}
    Boolean _returnValue = false;

    if (anyOutdoorSports.GetType() == typeof(List<Swimming>))
    {
        List<Swimming> Swimming = anyOutdoorSports.Cast<Swimming>().ToList();

        if (Swimming.Count > 0)
        {
            int listCount = (from rca in Swimming
                             where (rca.RecordFields[numberOfPartcipants].ToString()).StartsWith("stamina")
                             select rca).Count();
            _returnValue = listCount > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
    else if (anyOutdoorSports.GetType() == typeof(List<Tennis>))
    {
        List<Tennis> Tennis = anyOutdoorSports.Cast<Tennis>().ToList();

        if (Tennis.Count > 0)
        {
            int listCount = (from rca in Tennis
                             where (rca.RecordFields[numberOfPartcipants].ToString()).StartsWith("stamina")
                             select rca).Count();
            _returnValue = listCount > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
    else if (anyOutdoorSports.GetType() == typeof(List<Soccer>))
    {
        List<Soccer> Soccer = anyOutdoorSports.Cast<Soccer>().ToList();

        if (Soccer.Count > 0)
        {
            int listCount = (from rca in Soccer
                             where (rca.RecordFields[numberOfPartcipants].ToString()).StartsWith("stamina")
                             select rca).Count();
            _returnValue = listCount > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }

    return _returnValue;
}
```

THANKS TO ALL WHO VIEWED AND HELPED.

Comment: If `Swimming`, `Tennis`, and `Soccer` derive from the same base class, you shouldn't be using a generic, but a method that takes `List<BaseClass>`.

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward if there is a common base class for `Tennis`, `Soccer` and `Swimming` with a `RecordFields` property:

```
private boolean FilterList<T>(IEnumerable<T> anyOutdoorSports, int numberOfParticipants) where T : OutdoorSport
{
    if(anyOutdoorSports == null) return false;
    return anyOutdoorSports.Any(s => s.RecordFields[numberOfParticipants].ToString().StartsWith("stamina"));
}
```

Comment: Though 'RecordFields' is a property in the base class for all the child classes, i still get the following error.
is it coz, 'RecordFields' is ReadOnly in both base and deriving class ?
'T' does not contain a definition for 'RecordFields' and no extension method 'RecordFields' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @CocaCola - Do you have the `where` constraint in the method definition i.e. `where T : BaseClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your types seem to have an RecordFields property you could add an Interface and use that instead of the Generic.

Other than that you'd have to resort to Func<> expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the classes inherit from the same base class, which contains `RecordFields`, you can create a generic constraint on the method and remove the `ifs` entirely.

```
private Boolean filterList<T>(List<T> anyOutdoorSports, int numberOfPartcipants)
  where T : OutdoorSport
{
    if (anyOutdoorSports == null){ return false ;}
    Boolean _returnValue = false;

    if (anyOutdoorSports.Count > 0)
    {
        int listCount = (from rca in anyOutdoorSports
                         where (rca.RecordFields[numberOfPartcipants].ToString()).StartsWith("stamina")
                         select rca).Count();
        _returnValue = listCount > 0;
    }

    return _returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Though 'RecordFields' is a property in the base class for all the child classes, i still get the following error.
is it coz, 'RecordFields' is ReadOnly in both base and deriving class ?
'T' does not contain a definition for 'RecordFields' and no extension method 'RecordFields' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @CocaCola, did you add the "where T : OutdoorSport" to the method signature?